# “With vs Having” Showing Possession

Tags: difference, possessives

I have a problem with the words "having" and "with" in the following context:

> 1. The computer is a machine having different parts.
> 2. The computer is a machine with different parts.

Do these sentences mean the same thing or they have different meanings?

Answer (score 1):

Although "having" is not wrong in that sentence, it does sound a bit odd. It could be replaced by "that has" or "which has":

> The computer is a machine that has different parts.
>
> The computer is a machine which has different parts.

I feel that "having" is reserved for more unusual/interesting information:

> The piano is the instrument having the greatest number of octaves.

So by saying "having" you're implying that the information is more interesting than usual. Most machines have different parts, so it's not unusual that a computer, being a machine, would also have different parts.

Using "having" places emphasis on the information, whereas "with" does not.